# Search Engine Friendly page link issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, zen-cart

Suppose my testimonial link is domain.com/index.php?main_page=display_all_testimonials . And testimonials are generated from dynamically with different module. And it is made up with zen cart framework . But now my client wants that testimonial link should be domain.com/wedding-flower-testimonials .

Is it possible to show the page link is domain.com/wedding-flower-testimonials but page content show from domain.com/index.php?main_page=display_all_testimonials modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^wedding-flower-testimonials/?$ /index.php?main_page=display_all_testimonials [L,NC,QSA]
```